# Generative Design in Minecraft: Removing Environment elements without damaging terrain

Tags: python, performance, loops, minecraft

I am currently working on a Generative Design in Minecraft Challenge and need some help with a task. The task is to remove elements from the environment such as oak logs, leaves, etc. without damaging the terrain. I currently have a working solution but its super inefficient and borderline unusable.

Here is the code:

```
import sys
from gdpc import __url__, Editor, Block, geometry, Box
from gdpc.exceptions import InterfaceConnectionError, BuildAreaNotSetError
from gdpc.vector_tools import *
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

blocks_to_remove = {
    Block("minecraft:oak_leaves").id,
    Block("minecraft:pine_leaves").id,
    Block("minecraft:birch_leaves").id,
    Block("minecraft:jungle_leaves").id,
    Block("minecraft:acacia_leaves").id,
    Block("minecraft:spruce_leaves").id,
    Block("minecraft:dark_oak_leaves").id,
    Block("minecraft:oak_log").id,
    Block("minecraft:pine_log").id,
    Block("minecraft:birch_log").id,
    Block("minecraft:jungle_log").id,
    Block("minecraft:acacia_log").id,
    Block("minecraft:spruce_log").id,
    Block("minecraft:dark_oak_log").id,
    Block("minecraft:cactus").id,
    Block("minecraft:tall_grass").id,
    Block("minecraft:double_plant").id,
    Block("minecraft:yellow_flower").id,
    Block("minecraft:red_flower").id,
    Block("minecraft:brown_mushroom").id,
    Block("minecraft:red_mushroom").id,
    Block("minecraft:vine").id,
    Block("minecraft:sugar_cane").id,
    Block("minecraft:pumpkin").id,
    Block("minecraft:cocoa").id,
    Block("minecraft:snow_layer").id,
    Block("minecraft:red_concrete").id,
    Block("minecraft:mushroom_stem").id,
}


def remove():
    editor = Editor()
    editor.buffering = True
    editor.bufferLimit = 512
    editor.multithreading = True
    try:
        editor.checkConnection()
    except InterfaceConnectionError:
        print(
            f"Error: Could not connect to the GDMC HTTP interface at {editor.host}!\n"
            'To use GDPC, you need to use a "backend" that provides the GDMC HTTP interface.\n'
            "For example, by running Minecraft with the GDMC HTTP mod installed.\n"
            f"See {__url__}/README.md for more information."
        )
        sys.exit(1)

    try:
        buildArea = editor.getBuildArea()
    except BuildAreaNotSetError:
        print(
            "Error: failed to get the build area!\n"
            "Make sure to set the build area with the /setbuildarea command in-game.\n"
            "For example: /setbuildarea ~0 0 ~0 ~64 200 ~64"
        )
        sys.exit(1)

    buildRectangle = buildArea.toRect()

    # Create a box of air from the max_surface_height

    worldslice = editor.loadWorldSlice(buildRectangle)
    print("Loaded world slice")

    # heightmap = worldslice.heightmaps["MOTION_BLOCKING_NO_LEAVES"]
    heightmap = worldslice.heightmaps["WORLD_SURFACE"]

    print("loaded heightmap")

    max_surface_height = np.max(heightmap)
    min_surface_height = np.min(heightmap)


    print(min_surface_height)
    print(max_surface_height)

    points_to_remove = []
    for x in range(buildArea.begin[0], buildArea.end[0]):
        for y in range(min_surface_height, max_surface_height):
            for z in range(buildArea.begin[2], buildArea.end[2]):

                # editor.placeBlock((x,y,z), Block("oak_log"))

                block = editor.getBlock((x, y, z))
                # print(block)
                if block.id in blocks_to_remove:
                    print((x, y, z))
                    points_to_remove.append((x, y, z))
                    editor.placeBlock((x, y, z), Block("air"))


def main():
    remove()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My approach (naive) was to iterate through all the blocks and see if any of the blocks were needed to be removed, if so their coordinate was saved, and then removed at the end. I don't know what else to do to be able to remove this type of terrain faster. Is there some sort of package/utility that I should be using?